# WPF TextBox border on Windows7

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-7, textbox

In Windows7 (maybe vista too), TextBoxes now get a blue emphasis rect when they receive input focus or get the MouseOver.

In my WPF app, that blue focus rect really sticks out like a sore thumb - it does NOT match the visual style of the rest of the app.

How do I disable it - or better yet, customise it?

(Setting FocusVisualStyle to {x:Null} in the xaml does nothing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the default style applied for the TextBox. To modify this behavior you have to create a custom style/template. just have a look at this sample

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="#FF8F8F8F" BorderBrush="#FF585858" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Silver"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.15"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Silver"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```