# Disabling a controls FocusVisualStyle?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to disable the FocusVisualStyle of a newly created textbox. As far as I understand you just need to add: FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" but for some reason the border of the textbox is still changing. The full thing is:

```
<TextBox FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,264,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TextBox border on Windows7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328333/wpf-textbox-border-on-windows7)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting BorderThickness="0" , better yet create a trigger when does that when IsFocused = True